# How to split a string that contains square brackets with spaces in it

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split, format

I'm trying to split the following string:

```
"add galaxy [Milky way] elliptical 13.2B"
```

the resulting array I want to achieve should contain the following strings:

```
"add","galaxy","Milky way","eliptical","13.2B"
```

I tried using string.Split() and experimented with different method parameters, but I didn't achieve what I wanted.

How can I achieve this result?

EDIT:
I found a way to do it using a regular expression.

```
@"[A-Za-z0-9.]+|(#.*?#)|(\[.*?\])"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick and dirty solution. Doesn't account for the possibility of multiple spaces or multiple nested `[[[]]]` though.

```cs
string[] split(string s)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    bool inBlock = false;

    for(; end < s.Length; end++)
    {
        if (s[end] == '[')
        {
            inBlock = true;
            start++;
        }
        else if(s[end] == ']' && inBlock)
        {
            inBlock = false;
            list.Add(s.Substring(start, end - start));
            end++;
            start = end + 1;
        }
        else if(s[end] == ' ' && !inBlock)
        {
            list.Add(s.Substring(start, end - start));
            start = end + 1;
        }
    }
    if(end > start)
        list.Add(s.Substring(start, end - start));

    return list.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using split, you can also use [Regex.Matches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=net-5.0).

```
(?<=\[)[^][]+(?=])|(?<=#)[^#]+(?=#)|[A-Za-z0-9.]+
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\[)[^][]+(?=])`Assert `[` to the left, and `]` to the right and match all in between
- `|` Or
- `(?<=#)[^#]+(?=#)` Assert `#` to the left, and `#` to the right and match all o in between
- `|` Or
- `[A-Za-z0-9.]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed in the character class

See a [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5c%5b%29%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d%2b%28%3f%3d%5d%29%7c%28%3f%3c%3d%23%29%5b%5e%23%5d%2b%28%3f%3d%23%29%7c%5bA-Za-z0-9.%5d%2b&i=add+galaxy+%5bMilky+way%5d+elliptical+13.2B+%23test+test+%23) or a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/BqAWxV)

For example

```
string pattern = @"(?<=\[)[^][]*(?=])|(?<=#)[^#]*(?=#)|[A-Za-z0-9.]+";
string input = @"add galaxy [Milky way] elliptical 13.2B #test test #";    
String[] matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern)
           .Cast<Match>()
           .Select(m => m.Value)
           .ToArray();

foreach (String m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m);
}
```

Output

```
add
galaxy
Milky way
elliptical
13.2B
test test
```

---

If you want that result using [Regex.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=net-5.0), you can use capture groups in the patter (inside the outer `#` or square brackets) to keep the delimiter in the output and remove the empty entries in the array.

```
string pattern = @"([A-Za-z0-9.]+)|#([^#]+)#|\[([^][]+)]";
string input = @"add galaxy [Milky way] elliptical 13.2B #test test #";
string[] items = Regex.Split(input, pattern).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray();

foreach (string item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Output

```
add
galaxy
Milky way
elliptical
13.2B
test test
```

See a [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5bA-Za-z0-9.%5d%2b%29%7c%23%28%5b%5e%23%5d%2b%29%23%7c%5c%5b%28%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d%2b%29%5d&i=add+galaxy+%5bMilky+way%5d+elliptical+13.2B+%23test+test+%23)  or a  [C# demo](https://ideone.com/aJW4dG)